# Second order pde problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A general second order partial differential equation of the form :

$Au_{xx} + Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} + Du_x + Eu_y + F = 0$ is solved by finding the characteristics equations by :

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $\frac{B \pm \sqrt{B^{2}-4AC}}{2A}$ , and then letting $C_1$ as equation (1) and $C_2$ as equation (2) , transform into canonical form and hence solve it.

But what happens if A = 0 , how to proceed in such a situation , kindly help !

Comment: If A=0. that means instead of quadratic formula, you'd have to use normal factorisation, for e.g, in $ax^2+bx+c=0$ if $a=0$ $\implies$ $bx+c=0$ ,  quadratic formula won't be defined.

Comment: I still don't get it , consider : $u_{xy} + yu_{yy} + sin(x+y) = 0$ , how to proceed in this situation ? @Mann

Comment: Notice that the roles of $x$ and $y$ can be exchanged: these are just some names for some variables. The PDE in your last comment can be treated as you would treat $ xu_{xx} + u_{xy} + \sin(x+y) = 0$